# Tomcat 8 redirect to https8443

Tags: web, https, tomcat8

I deployed my application on `Tomcat 8`. Whenever I am trying to access it. It automatically redirects to HTTPS.

Could some one help so that i can understand why it is happening.

I have not changed anything in web.xml, context.xml and server.xml.

For default application it is running on http.

But for deployed application it is redirecting to HTTPS - 8443.

Comment: web.xml for your application please

Comment: Thanks Thomas!! I got the solution. Reason I was using this in my web.xml - <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>

Comment: I removed https to http and it started work.Thanks